# Excel VBA - Recover user form deleted by mistake

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

By mistake I have deleted my userform in Excel VBA. How to restore the user form? Could anyone help me in resolving my issue? It's almost a week's work.

Comment: Close without saving, reopen?

Comment: On the bright side, every single time I had to rewrite/reimplement some code - without fail - the 2nd time around was much, much better =)

Comment: Assuming you are on Windows, have you tried "Restore Previous Versions", (or Time Machine on a Mac)?

Comment: ^^ or, if you're working off your company's file server, ask IT if they can restore the previous day's backup. If you were working locally... I'm sorry. When you remove a module from a VBA project, the VBE prompts whether you want to export the module - did you export it? If so, you could simply re-import it back.

Comment: No, i didnt exported it. :( . any other option..PLs

Comment: Well, you were prompted to confirm, and confirmed. If you don't have backups, there's no magic solution.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad suggested solutions for both Win & Mac to get back older versions, and Mat suggested contacting your IT department if this is a corporate machine. Those would be your other options...

Answer (score 3):

Happens to every single one of us - *once*. Then, we start **making copies and backups**!

You confirmed the deletion, and then (presumably) saved the changes. If you accidentally confirm a deletion, you can revert back to the previous saved version by closing without saving, then re-opening the file - losing everything *since the last time you saved*.

If you're working off a corporate file server, your IT department likely has a recent backup of it; you'll lose everything *since the last backup*.

When you delete a module from a VBA project, the IDE prompts you to confirm and asks whether you want to export the file - make it a habit to *always* click the "yes" button, even if you're not planning to reuse that code. Then you can always discard the file if you *really* don't need it, but then more importantly it makes a copy that you can re-import again if something went wrong.

> It's almost a week's work.

I'm sorry this isn't what you want to hear, but you're probably going to have to rewrite it. The good news, is that now you know what you're doing; you can probably rewrite it all in much less time than that.

---

Another safety net: use **source control**. Regularly export your code files to a `git` repository, and commit the changes. You can then keep the repository local, or push it to BitBucket or GitHub - and then restore any commit, from any computer, at any given time.